# Make file into Blob on TypeScript for Ionic

Tags: typescript, firebase, blob, ionic3

I'm trying to upload a Blob file into Firebase but I keep getting "undefined" as return of the "makeFileIntoBlob" function. I'm running it on Android.
I Can get the filepath after taking picture but when I call the function to retrieve a Blob to upload it on Firebase, I get the Blob file as "undefined".
Some Help?

Heres the Function where I upload the image to Firebase Storage

```
uploadToFirebase(imageBlob) {  
var fileName = 'sample.jpg';
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
var fileRef = firebase.storage().ref('Animais/' + fileName);

var uploadTask = fileRef.put(imageBlob);

uploadTask.on('state_changed', (snapshot) => {
  console.log('snapshot progess ' + snapshot);
}, (_error) => {
  reject(_error);
}, () => {
  // completion...
  resolve(uploadTask.snapshot);
});
});
}
```

Heres the Function where I try to Make a Blob from FilePath

```
makeFileIntoBlob(imagePath) {

var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = (evt: any) => {
    var imgBlob: any = new Blob(imagePath);
    imgBlob.name = 'sample.jpg';
    return imgBlob;
};
reader.onerror = (e) => {
    console.log('Failed file read: ' + e.toString());
};
```

Heres the function where I Take the Picture

```
takePic(){

let imageSource;

this.camera.getPicture({
    destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: imageSource,
    encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    targetHeight: 640,
    correctOrientation: true,
    saveToPhotoAlbum : true
}).then((imagePath) => {
    alert('got image path ' + imagePath);
    // convert picture to blob
    return this.makeFileIntoBlob(imagePath);
}).then((imageBlob) => {
    alert('got image blob ' + imageBlob);
    // upload the blob
    return this.uploadToFirebase(imageBlob);
}).then((uploadSnapshot: any) => {
    alert('file uploaded successfully  ' + uploadSnapshot.downloadURL);
    // store reference to storage in database
    return this.saveToDatabaseAssetList(uploadSnapshot);
}).then((uploadSnapshot: any) => {
    //alert('file saved to asset catalog successfully  ');
}, (error) => {
    alert('Error ' + (error.message || error));
});
```

Comment: Are you really using TypeScript?  What compiler errors are you getting?  What is `BLOB`?

Comment: Yep, Typescript, Ionic3. Sorry for the BLOB, just sort of debugging I was trying, already edited it. I'm not getting compiler erros, I'm just getting "undefined" as return of the function "makeFileIntoBlob".

Comment: This might be a duplicate of [Javascript Promises with FileReader()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495796/javascript-promises-with-filereader), since your issue is that you are using a `FileReader` but not using its callbacks to resolve/reject a `Promise`.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment, your issue is that you are using a `FileReader` but not using its callbacks to resolve/reject a `Promise`.  You need to return a `Promise` instead.  You're also not actually using the `FileReader` to read anything from `imagePath`, but I don't even know if that would work because `FileReader` reads `File`s or `Blob`s, not URIs.  If the URI is a `data://` URI you can convert it into a `Blob` with some code.  If it's a `file://` URI then you don't have permission to do that in a browser unless you are [chrome-privileged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25046301/convert-url-to-file-or-blob-for-filereader-readasdataurl).  Wait, are you in a browser?

Unfortunately I don't think you [posted enough info for anyone to reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Are you using [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/index.html#module_camera.getPicture)?  If so, why not use the returned `file://` url with the [File Transfer API](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/index.html) instead of trying to pass it through a `FileReader`?  If that doesn't work I can't really help you because I don't know anything about Cordova.  You might want to add a tag so other people can help you.  And be sure to search StackOverflow for other [relevant questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25637603/in-phonegap-file-reader-is-not-reading-the-file-by-using-the-path-getting-by-fil) that might be applicable.

Good luck!